# Trouble Aligning Columns in Form

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating an online form and having a bit of trouble aligning the input boxes in the form. I've tried `<br>`, but it's always slightly off. I'm assuming this is affecting the text below as well.

Also, is **PHPMailer** still the preferred(simplest) way to go to retrieve the data user's input and attach? Some files might be pretty large.

```css
head,
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #0C2440;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 110px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=date],
select {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Mileage Certification Change Request Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700,800" media="all" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('date').value = Date();

    //   document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
    //     location.href = "confirmation.html";
    //     return false;
    //   };

    //   document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    //   anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //       e.preventDefault();

    //       document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
    //           behavior: 'smooth'
    //       });
    //   });
    // });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Planning Department</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h2>Mileage Change Request Form</h2>
  <br>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <br>
        <div class="column">
          Date of Submittal:<br>
          <input type="date" id="date" name="date"><br> County Name:<br>
          <input type="text" id="county" name="county"><br> City/Town Name:<br>
          <input type="text" id="cityname" name="cityname"><br> Name of Office and Title:<br>
          <input type="text" id="officename" name="officename"><br> Address:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br> City:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          State:<br>
          <input type="text" id="state" name="address"><br> ZIP Code:<br>
          <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip"><br> Telephone:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br> Fax:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="fax" name="fax"><br> Email:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br> Comments:
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="reqs">
          <br>
          <p><b>Before we can make any changes, you MUST include items 1-3 for each submission. For annexations with mileage changes, you MUST include items 1-4. If you only have an annexation with no changes to mileage, item 4 is all you need to submit.</b></p>
          <ol>
            <li>Copy of a current (scaled) map(s) depicting the roads that need added and/or removed OR a shapefile or file geodatabase. If none of these are available, provide a copy of measurable (Scaled) plats depicting the roads that need added/removed.</li>
            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
            <li>Copy of meeting minutes at which a governing body accepted the roads into your system. If unavailable, please provide a letter stating the acceptance of the roads signed by an elected official. An example acceptance letter is available if
              needed.</li> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
            <li>A list of each road and its requested mileage.</li> <input id="fileSelect" name="spreadsheet" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" required>
            <li>Copy of annexation ordinance(s) establishing the new corporate limits along with a shapefile and/or file geodatabase of the correct corporate limits. If a shapefile is not available provide a drawing of the correct corporate limits on a scaled
              map.</li> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
  <!--   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $emailAddress = '';
     require "class.phpmailer.php";
    $msg = 'Date:'.$_POST['date'].'<br /> County:'.$_POST['county'].'<br /> City/Town Name:'.$_POST['cityname'].'<br /> Name of Office and Title: '.$_POST['officename']. '<br /> Address: '.$_POST['address']. '<br /> City: '.POST['city'], '<br /> State: $_POST['state']. '<br /> ZIP Code: '.POST['zip']. '<br /> Telephone: '.$_POST['phone']. '<br /> Fax: '.$_POST['fax']. '<br /> Email: '.$_POST['email']. '<br /> Comments: '$_POST['comments']. '<br />';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->IsMail();

      $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
      $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
      $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
      $mail->Subject = "Subject";
      $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
      $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail->Send();

      echo'<script> window.location="../MCCR.html"; </script> ';
    }
  ?> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `PHPMailer` is the way to send and emails, not retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<br>` and use CSS style. Added some style in your existing code as

```
// newly added style begin
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:30px 0;
}

fieldset {
  padding-top:20px;
}
.form-fields {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
input {
  width:100%;
}
//end
```

```css
head,
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #0C2440;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.header img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 110px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=date],
select {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

// newly added style begin
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:30px 0;
}

fieldset {
  padding-top:20px;
}
.form-fields {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
  width:50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
input {
  width:100%;
}
//end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Web Mileage Certification Change Request Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700,800" media="all" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
  <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //document.getElementById('date').value = Date();

    //   document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
    //     location.href = "confirmation.html";
    //     return false;
    //   };

    //   document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    //   anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //       e.preventDefault();

    //       document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
    //           behavior: 'smooth'
    //       });
    //   });
    // });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Planning Department</h1>
  </div>
  <h2>Mileage Change Request Form</h2>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-fields">
          <div class="column">
          Date of Submittal:
          <input type="date" id="date" name="date"> County Name:
          <input type="text" id="county" name="county"> City/Town Name:
          <input type="text" id="cityname" name="cityname"> Name of Office and Title:
          <input type="text" id="officename" name="officename"> Address:
          <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> City:
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          State:
          <input type="text" id="state" name="address"> ZIP Code:
          <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip"> Telephone:
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> Fax:
          <input type="text" id="fax" name="fax"> Email:
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email"> Comments:
          <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reqs">
          <p><b>Before we can make any changes, you MUST include items 1-3 for each submission. For annexations with mileage changes, you MUST include items 1-4. If you only have an annexation with no changes to mileage, item 4 is all you need to submit.</b></p>
          <ol>
            <li>Copy of a current (scaled) map(s) depicting the roads that need added and/or removed OR a shapefile or file geodatabase. If none of these are available, provide a copy of measurable (Scaled) plats depicting the roads that need added/removed.</li>
            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
            <li>Copy of meeting minutes at which a governing body accepted the roads into your system. If unavailable, please provide a letter stating the acceptance of the roads signed by an elected official. An example acceptance letter is available if
              needed.</li> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
            <li>A list of each road and its requested mileage.</li> <input id="fileSelect" name="spreadsheet" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" required>
            <li>Copy of annexation ordinance(s) establishing the new corporate limits along with a shapefile and/or file geodatabase of the correct corporate limits. If a shapefile is not available provide a drawing of the correct corporate limits on a scaled
              map.</li> <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" required>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
  <!--   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $emailAddress = '';
     require "class.phpmailer.php";
    $msg = 'Date:'.$_POST['date'].'<br /> County:'.$_POST['county'].'<br /> City/Town Name:'.$_POST['cityname'].'<br /> Name of Office and Title: '.$_POST['officename']. '<br /> Address: '.$_POST['address']. '<br /> City: '.POST['city'], '<br /> State: $_POST['state']. '<br /> ZIP Code: '.POST['zip']. '<br /> Telephone: '.$_POST['phone']. '<br /> Fax: '.$_POST['fax']. '<br /> Email: '.$_POST['email']. '<br /> Comments: '$_POST['comments']. '<br />';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->IsMail();

      $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
      $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
      $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
      $mail->Subject = "Subject";
      $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
      $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail->Send();

      echo'<script> window.location="../MCCR.html"; </script> ';
    }
  ?> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Is there a quick way to center the entire form (but keep text to the left of each form field?

Comment: @574393984 I have updated the solution and `width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;` to  `.form-fields` element